# having trouble using a Count() command in combination with Join

Tags: mysql

I've noticed there's alot of similar questions, but after trying to put their answers to practice in mine, nothing seems to work.
I'm trying to do a task currently that revolves around the world database that MYSQL provides. [1] https://dev.mysql.com/doc/world-setup/en/

Currently I'm trying to select data that is within two tables and drawn out via the countrycode column. This is working just fine, but once I try to add the count command to the code, things start to fail.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT c.name,
c.continent,
c.population,
c.code, cy.name as capital_city
count(cy.countrycode)
from country c
left join city cy
on c.code=cy.countrycode AND c.capital = cy.id
where cy.countrycode = "GBR"
limit 1;
```

Ive also tried instead:

```
SELECT c.name,
c.continent,
c.population,
c.code, cy.name as capital_city
(Select Count (*)
    from cy
    where countrycode ="GBR") as total_cities
from country c
left join city cy
on c.code=cy.countrycode AND c.capital = cy.id
where cy.countrycode = "GBR"
limit 1;
```

I am still very new to MYSQL so any pointers on how to make better code would be great, but I really would like to find out to get a total_cities value to be added to my query that is already pulling from two tables for other required data (in this case data about population, name of country, country code, capital city.

*Database Structure:*
**Country Table:**
Code
Continent
Region
Population
GNP
GNPold
LocalName
Capital
Code2

**City Table:**
ID
Name
CountryCode
District
Population

Comment: Can you paste the error message?

Comment: Whats the point of count with limit 1

Comment: My bad, limit 1, was there before when i had not fully developed all my join conditions. You can ignore "limit 1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you would want to have the country name, continent, the population, code, capital city and number of cities in Great Britain.

You don't need to use LIMIT here as a country has just one capital. Secondly, to get the total number of cities you are suppose to read from the table city and not `cy`.

```
SELECT
    c.name, c.continent, c.population, c.code, cy.name capital_city,
    (SELECT 
          COUNT(*) 
     FROM city WHERE countrycode ='GBR') as total_cities
FROM
    (SELECT
          name, continent, population, code, capital
     FROM country WHERE countrycode='GBR') c 
LEFT JOIN 
    city cy
ON c.code=cy.countrycode AND c.capital=cy.id;
```

Comment: Just tried this, its apparently saying that the column "continent" doesnt exist...

Comment: @KevinMan Could you add the structure of the two tables to your question? From your query I kind of see a column continent in your country table.

Comment: Ive added the database structure to my Orignal post now. But I understand that MY table has a continent column, im just not sure why its giving me such an error with the command line.

Comment: Ok I have adjusted my query. Try again. I did this; `(SELECT
          name, continent, population, code, capital
     FROM city WHERE countrycode='GBR') c ` instead of `(SELECT
          name, continent, population, code, capital
     FROM country WHERE countrycode='GBR') c `. Try again.

Comment: Yeah, im having the same issue as before, but now with the countryCode. your line for count keeps grabbing data from two tables but are not allowing it to.